# Sails js using models outside web server

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

I want to create a cli to create admin users I have the user model setup in api/models/User.js

and in cli on

```
var User, program;

program = require("commander");

User = require("../api/models/User");

program.version("0.0.1");

program.command("create_user").description("Create a user into database").action(function() {
  return console.log(User);
});

program.parse(process.argv);
```

User log is:

```
    User = {
      attributes: {
        username: "string",
        password: "string",
      }
    };
```

and no waterline methods available to use.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `sails run <command>`.

Simply create `<appPath>/commands/index.js` with this content:

```js
module.exports = {
    testcommand: function (done) {
        // .. your code
        console.log('this is my testcommand');
        done();
    }
}
```

now you can run `sails run testcommand`

Comment: Nice, which versions supports this?

Comment: In sails 0.10.0 `sails run` was removed.

Comment: @Edy Was `sails run` removed entirely, or replaced with something similar?

Comment: @InternalFX it was removed in 0.10 entirely.

there is an open issue to bring `sails run` back: https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/1421

Comment: sails is not going to add this.. as there is a 'sails console' and a 'sails load' which can be used alternatively to do something similar. This here details the reason: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123090/using-waterline-model-outside-sailsjs-api

Answer (score 2):

If any one needs this:

```
sails = require("sails");
sails.lift({
  log: {
    level: 'silent'
  }
}, function() {
  User.create(obj);
  process.stdin.destroy();
});
```