# Sail.js requires server restart after running command to refresh database

Tags: node.js, sails.js

From this question, [Sails js using models outside web server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16739291/sails-js-using-models-outside-web-server) I learned how to run a command from the terminal to update records. However, when I do this the changes don't show up until I restart the server. I'm using the sails-disk adapter and v0.9

Comment: Howdy, can you give us a bit more detail on what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to delete records that are older than a certain time. They way I thought to do this was with a cron job that would run a command in sails. Something like 'sails run deleteExpireRecords'. This works from the command line, but the records are still available until I restart the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-disk/blob/f94377e8541747f763ebf77df6d48a2140597fc4/index.js), the application using `sails-disk` adapter loads the data from file only once, when the corresponding Waterline collection [is being created](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-disk/blob/f94377e8541747f763ebf77df6d48a2140597fc4/index.js#L47). After that all the `update`s and `destroy`s happen in the memory, then the data is being dumped to the file, but not being re-read.

That said, what's happening in your case is that once your server is running, it doesn't matter if you are changing the DB file (`.tmp/disk.db`) using your CLI instance, 'cause lifted Sails server won't know about the changes until it's restarted.

Long story short, the solution is simple: use another adapter. I would suggest you to check out [sails-mongo](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-mongo) or [sails-redis](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails-redis) (though the latter is still in development), for both Mongo and Redis have data auto expiry functionality (http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/, http://redis.io/commands/expire). Besides, `sails-disk` is not production-suitable anyways, so sooner or later you would need something else.

Comment: @bodagetta No problem. You can also accept the answer if you think it's the right one, so other people could see where to look. ;)

Answer (score 2):

One way to accomplish deleting "expired records" over time is by rolling your own "cron-like job" in `/config/bootstrap.js`.  In psuedo code it would look something like this:

```
module.exports.bootstrap = function (cb) {

  setInterval(function() {  < Insert Model Delete Code here>  }, 300000);

  cb();
};
```

The downside to this approach is if it throws it will stop the server.  You might also take a look at [kue](https://npmjs.org/package/kue).