# Using Waterline model outside SailsJS api

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

Is it possible to use models defined within `[app-name]/api/models` outside `api` folder?

I have created separate folder in application root, where I placed cron job that should fill my database every hour. I would like to reuse Models defined inside my `api` folder, but not sure how to do it.

I see that I can do `sails.lift` inside that cron script but that doesn't seem very nice to me.

Did someone experience something similar? I'm new to node.js, so maybe I'm missing something pretty obvious.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If your concern with using `sails.lift` is that it starts an actual HTTP server that listens for requests, you can use `sails.load` instead.  It will do everything that `lift` does--including loading hooks and models--*except* for starting the server.

```
var Sails = require('sails');
Sails.load(function(err, sails) {
   // At this point you have access to all your models, services, etc.
});
```

Comment: Looks like this is what I was looking for! I'll give it a try and let you know!

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the thing I was looking for! Thanks a lot!

Comment: I was needing this for working with my models from a node.js script, thank you

Comment: Use `process.exit()` to shut down the script when complete. Unless there is a sails method.

Comment: @gotmikhail yep, works for me, just wrote a sails script for Heroku scheduler using the snippet above