# Mandrill API does not send email when running as scheduled job

Tags: node.js, heroku, sails.js

I have a scheduled job that I need to send daily emails out to customers.

Right now I am just testing the basic framework that I will use so I have [Node Heroku Scheduler](https://addons.heroku.com/scheduler) trying to send a test email every 10 minutes using the [Mandrill API](https://mandrillapp.com/api/docs/index.nodejs.html).

In normal operating situations I can send the test email successfully using the following back-end code:

**Controller:**

```
sendTestEmail: function (req, res) {

console.log("Trying to send the hourly email.");

var emailInfo = {
    message: "Sample Message - should send hourly.",
    subject: "Hourly email test",
    fromEmail: "collegepregame@gmail.com",
    fromName: "SmallChangeProject",
    to: "zach_cook@texasca.com",
    name: "Zachary Cook"
};

EmailService.simpleSendEmail(emailInfo, function(err, message) {
    if (err) {
        console.log("Email did not send.", err);
        res.send(404, '\n\nerror occurred\n\n');
    }

    console.log("Message sent: ", message);
    return res.send(message);
});

}
```

That `EmailService` code looks like this:

**Service:**

```
var mandrill = require('mandrill-api/mandrill');
var mandrill_client = new mandrill.Mandrill('dDIJDHIDDEN2893KEYUNDSECRET');

module.exports = {

  simpleSendEmail: function (emailInfo, cb) {

    var message = {
      "html": emailInfo.message || "Accidental email, please ignore",
      "text": emailInfo.text || "Example text content",
      "subject": emailInfo.subject || "Password Reset Email",
      "from_email": emailInfo.fromEmail || "customerservice@smallchangeproj.com",
      "from_name": emailInfo.fromName || "SmallChangeProject",
      "to": [{
        "email": emailInfo.to || "zacharycook2014@utexas.edu",
        "name": emailInfo.name || 'Name Unavailable'
      }],
      "headers": {
        "Reply-To": emailInfo.fromEmail || "customerservice@smallchangeproj.com"
      },
      "important": false,
      "track_opens": null,
      "track_clicks": null,
      "auto_text": null,
      "auto_html": null,
      "inline_css": null,
      "url_strip_qs": null,
      "preserve_recipients": null,
      "view_content_link": null,
      "tracking_domain": null,
      "signing_domain": null,
      "return_path_domain": null,
      "merge": true,
      "merge_language": "mailchimp"
    };
     var async = false;
     var ip_pool = "Main Pool";

     // console.log('\n-------\nprenteding to send the emails!\n-------\n');
    mandrill_client.messages.send({"message": message, "async": async, "ip_pool": ip_pool}, function(result) {
      console.log(result);
    }, function(e) {
      // Mandrill returns the error as an object with name and message keys
      console.log('A mandrill error occurred: ' + e.name + ' - ' + e.message);
      return cb('an error occurred');
      // A mandrill error occurred: Unknown_Subaccount - No subaccount exists with the id 'customer-123'
    });

    return cb(null, 'email has been sent');

  }

};
```

Ok so all of that works. The problem is when I try to send it using a scheduled job.

I borrowed a concept from [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24123090/using-waterline-model-outside-sailsjs-api) and the Gitter channel for SailsJS where I asked for help. I was recommended to use `Sails.lift()` to get my scheduled job to be able to operate in the environment is supposed to in order to use all my regular controllers, models, and services.

**UPDATED - I PUT ALL CODE IN THE SAME FILE TO HELP TROUBLESHOOT**

That code looks like so:

```
var Sails = require('sails');
var mandrill = require('mandrill-api/mandrill');
var mandrill_client = new mandrill.Mandrill('W9IVcGVz1E1oTmvG_KdiXQ');

Sails.lift(function(err, sails) {

    console.log("Trying to send the hourly email.");
    if (mandrill) {
        console.log("Have mandrill itself.");
    }

    if (mandrill_client) {
        console.log("Have mandrill client initiated.");
    }

    var emailInfo = {
      message: "Sample Message - should send hourly.",
      subject: "Hourly email test",
      fromEmail: "collegepregame@gmail.com",
      fromName: "SmallChangeProject",
      to: "zach_cook@texasca.com",
      name: "Zachary Cook"
    };

    var message = {
      "html": emailInfo.message || "Accidental email, please ignore",
      "text": emailInfo.text || "Example text content",
      "subject": emailInfo.subject || "Password Reset Email",
      "from_email": emailInfo.fromEmail || "customerservice@smallchangeproj.com",
      "from_name": emailInfo.fromName || "SmallChangeProject",
      "to": [{
        "email": emailInfo.to || "zacharycook2014@utexas.edu",
        "name": emailInfo.name || 'Name Unavailable'
      }],
      "headers": {
        "Reply-To": emailInfo.fromEmail || "customerservice@smallchangeproj.com"
      },
      "important": false,
      "track_opens": null,
      "track_clicks": null,
      "auto_text": null,
      "auto_html": null,
      "inline_css": null,
      "url_strip_qs": null,
      "preserve_recipients": null,
      "view_content_link": null,
      "tracking_domain": null,
      "signing_domain": null,
      "return_path_domain": null,
      "merge": true,
      "merge_language": "mailchimp"
    };
    var async = false;
    var ip_pool = "Main Pool";

    mandrill_client.messages.send({"message": message, "async": async, "ip_pool": ip_pool}, function(result) {
        console.log(result);
        console.log("Should have sent!");
    }, function(e) {
      console.log('A mandrill error occurred: ' + e.name + ' - ' + e.message);
    });

    console.log("Email should have sent.");

    process.exit();
});
```

In the console that gives me:

```
 Starting process with command `node scheduled-job.js` scheduler@addons.heroku.com
 heroku[scheduler.1963]: Starting process with command `node scheduled-job.js`
 heroku[scheduler.1963]: State changed from starting to up
 app[scheduler.1963]: Trying to send the hourly email.
 app[scheduler.1963]: Have mandrill itself.
 app[scheduler.1963]: Have mandrill client initiated.
 app[scheduler.1963]: Email should have sent.
 heroku[scheduler.1963]: State changed from up to complete
 heroku[scheduler.1963]: Process exited with status 0
```

The success messages make it seem like everything works and `EmailService.simpleSendEmail()` doesn't give me any errors - **but** no email is sent out.

What is the reason it is not sending, yet Mandrill gives me no error message? Will `sails.lift()` not work for sending scheduled emails?

Thanks for any/all help!

Best - Zach

Comment: Did you try logging into the Mandrill API dashboard to see if an email request was logged?  Have you looked in your Spam folder?

Comment: @JasonLivesay yes I did both!

Comment: Nothing in either....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `process.exit()` killed the scheduled task before the email could be sent.  Try taking that out.  If necessary you can call `process.exit()` in the callback where you get the result from the API call.

Comment: Ooooh ok that actually makes sense. Thank you!